# In Xamarin I need to set marker in the center of the map and get the position

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying in Xamarin to add a marker in the center of the map that marker will be fixe and can not be dragged, the map below that marker can be dragged normally. I need to get the position of the map that was chosen by the user, I searched a lot for the internet and found nothing that could help me. This feature is widely used in the Uber app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `iOS`, you can use the `RegionChanged` on a `MKMapViewDelegate` subclass to get updates as the user scrolls the map. Use the `MKMapView.Region` to get the center (`CLLocationCoordinate2D`) of the map's view;

```
class MyMapDelegate : MKMapViewDelegate
{
    public override void RegionChanged(MKMapView mapView, bool animated)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{mapView.Region.Center.Latitude} : {mapView.Region.Center.Longitude}");
        // Update your map's MKPointAnnotation's Coordinate to match the mapView.Region.Center
    }
}
```

On `Android`, you can use the `OnCameraMove` on the  `GoogleMap.IOnCameraMoveListener` to get updates as the user scrolls the map. Use `GoogleMap.CameraPosition.Target` to obtain the Lat/Long of the center of the map's view and update your `MarkerOptions`'s position:

```
public class MapCameraMoveListener : Java.Lang.Object, GoogleMap.IOnCameraMoveListener
{
    readonly GoogleMap googleMap;

    public MapCameraMoveListener(GoogleMap googleMap) { this.googleMap = googleMap; }

    public void OnCameraMove()
    {
        Log.Debug("SO", $"{googleMap?.CameraPosition.Target.Latitude} : {googleMap?.CameraPosition.Target.Longitude}");
        // Update your map's `MarkerOptions`'s position to match the CameraPosition.Target
    }
}
```

For `Xamarin.Forms` look at the samples on how to custom the map via custom renderers to implement those native features shown above:

- https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/

Comment: Thank you so much, my friend! I believe this is what I need!