# Xamarin Forms: How to get coordinates of a location using image placed on top of the map

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have map with relative layout and there is image(Fixed Image) placed in the center of the map, and the image is fixed(Not moveable).

**How can i get coordinates of the that location where the image(Fixed Image) is located?**

```xml
<RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

  <map x:Name="map" MapType="Street" IsShowingUser="True" RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=1 }" RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Heigth, Factor=1 }" />

  <Image x:Name="image" RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=map, Type=RelativeToView, Property=Width, Factor=0.5}" RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression ElementName=map, Type=RelativeToView, Property=Height, Factor=0.5}"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```cs
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
  public MapPage()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    image.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("myimagelocation.png", typeof(MapPage));
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that the map moves around but the image does not (i.e. like cross hairs) and you want the x/y center of the map in GPS coords?

Comment: You can get the coordinates of `image` by using image.X and image.Y, is that you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understood, your goal here is to get the position in the center of the presented part of the map.

if so, this has been asked before and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46895114/in-xamarin-i-need-to-set-marker-in-the-center-of-the-map-and-get-the-position)

it's a platform-specific code though

and this is a full tutorial on it too [Map Center Position Xamarin.Forms](http://alejandroruizvarela.blogspot.com/2015/07/map-center-position-xamarinforms.html)